# Translate a path by changing root

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm writing a bash script that will go through all files in `/home/someone/directory/`. I want to create a list of the files, but make the root `/home/someone/directory`, (transform  `/home/someone/directory` to `/`), so the output would look like this:

```
/file1
/file2
/dir1
/dir1/file1
```

Here's the same output without any translation:

```
/home/someone/directory/file1
/home/someone/directory/file2
/home/someone/directory/dir1
/home/someone/directory/dir1/file1
```

Is it possible to do this in bash?

Answer (score 0):

Use `cut`:

```
cut -d'/' -f1,5- infile
```

select only **f**ields number 1 and 5 to the last